# No Sound on MacBook Pro with Parallels

Tags: ios, audio, parallels

Here's the issue: it can happen that you create a new VM. You select CPU, RAM, HDD,... resources. Everything goods here. You start the VM, and BOOM, your MacBook audio go away

I searched for this problem a lot, 3 page of Google >_>, and finally found a solution

I hope works for you too :)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the **CPU & Memory** > **Advanced Settings** > **Hypervisor** change to **Apple**

[Original Discussion](https://forum.parallels.com/threads/no-sound-at-catalina-10-15-2-parallels-desktop-15-1-2-for-mac.349141/page-2)